# Ternary Operator Testing With Ava or Sinon

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, ava

I have a variable like this:

```
const domain_issuer = "some array of domains"
const url_setter = domain_issuer !== null ? domain_issuer[0] : '';
```

the domain_issuer is grabbing the domains from a config file that has arrays of different domains and it uses a regex to match a specific domain. So the url_setter checks to see if domain_issuer is null or not null and if it is null it assigns it to an empty string, if not, the first match gets assigned to url_setter

My branch coverage says the `''` (empty string) is not covered. I tried different things to reach that statement but nothing seems to work.

How can I cover this?

Comment: Your code is incorrect.  The value of `domain_issuer` variable always be `"some array of domains"`, the else condition never reach.

Comment: @slideshowp2 so the domain_issuer is grabbing the domains from a config file that has arrays of different domains and it uses a regex to match a specific domain. So the url_setter checks to see if domain_issuer is null or not null and if it is null it assigns it to an empty string, if not, the first match gets assigned to url_setter